# How to combine multiple Func<> delegates

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, predicate

How can I combine multiple Func delegates?

Assume I have two delegates

```
Func<bool> MovementButtonHold() => () => _inputSystem.MoveButtonHold
Func<bool> IsFreeAhead() => () => _TPG.IsFreeAhead();
```

Is there any way to combine these two delegates to one `Func<bool>` delegate?

Something like:

**And**

```
Func<bool> delegate1 = MovementButtonHold() && IsFreeAhead();
```

**Or**

```
Func<bool> delegate2 = MovementButtonHold() || IsFreeAhead();
```

Comment: You're just missing the `() =>` at the beginning.

Comment: Also your initial delegates are not defined correctly.  They should be `Func<bool> MovementButtonHold = () => _inputSystem.MoveButtonHold;` and `Func<bool> IsFreeAhead = () => _TPG.IsFreeAhead();`

Comment: @juharr that depends on if they are defined as methods. (recent syntax sugar)

Comment: @Nkosi In that case combining them would require `() => MovementButtonHold()() && IsFreeAhead()();`

Comment: Ahhh I see what you mean. Either way the OP needs to provide more details to clarify what they actually want.

Comment: Thank you, everything work great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code MovementButtonHold and IsFreeAhead are not delegates, they are methods that return delegates.
So to combine them you need something like this:

```
Func<bool> delegate1 = () => MovementButtonHold()() && IsFreeAhead()();
Func<bool> delegate2 = () => MovementButtonHold()() || IsFreeAhead()();
```

Note the ()() weird syntax above. The first () is to call the method and return the delegate, the second () is to call the delegate the return boolean result. Then you create an inline function to perform "AND" or "OR" operations on the outputs, and assign the inline function to delegate1 or delegate2

Unless you have a reason to make MovementButtonHold and IsFreeAhead return delegates you can simplify their implementations as follows to simply return the boolean result.

```
bool MovementButtonHold() => _inputSystem.MoveButtonHold;
bool IsFreeAhead() => _TPG.IsFreeAhead();

Func<bool> delegate1 = () => MovementButtonHold() && IsFreeAhead();
Func<bool> delegate2 = () => MovementButtonHold() || IsFreeAhead();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Func<bool> MovementButtonHold = () => true;
    Func<bool> IsFreeAhead = () => false;
    
    Func<bool> delegate1 = () => MovementButtonHold() && IsFreeAhead();
    Func<bool> delegate2 = () => MovementButtonHold() || IsFreeAhead();
```